# Network disabled on some wake-ups on saucy laptop

Tags: networking, suspend

Since I upgraded to Saucy Salamander 13.10, with every third suspend or so, the network is disabled and I'm unable to re-enable it. I've had to reboot to make it run again.

The network menu will have the option *Enable network* but clicking it will only produce a tick in the menu item, nothing else changes.

1. How can I make it enable automatically after suspend?
2. In the meantime, is there a workaround to at least manually re-enable it?

The PC is a Lenovo IdeaPad S205 using drivers r8169 and rt2800pci.

Comment: same here on Dell Studio 1550,Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100.     After wake-up I have to perform "sudo killall NetworkManager" to work again.

Comment: This is a confirmed bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1184262

Comment: The bug I filed myself was marked as duplicate of that one, but actually someone unmarked it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1243300

Comment: Bug was fixed in Saucy/Trusty.

Comment: I have similar problem in my DELL Inspiron N4010, I work around the problem by going to suspend and waking-up again.

Answer (score 25):

Use:

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/network-manager-resume
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/network-manager-resume
sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/network-manager-resume
```

Paste the following and save the file. This brings NetworkManager out of suspend mode:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# This script gets NetworkManager out of suspend.
case $1 in
     suspend|suspend_hybrid|hibernate)
    # No need to do anything here.
        ;;
     resume|thaw)
    nmcli nm sleep false
        ;;
esac
```

---

<sub>**Source**: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1184262/comments/23</sub>

Comment: I accepted this answer but I'm removing it now because I just had another resume without Network Manager waking up.

Comment: After making the file executable, worked for me.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. Re-accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry for unaccepting answer again, but I'm still having the same problem. I work around it by doing `sudo nmcli nm sleep false` when it happens. I haven't bothered to test development sources (as suggested in response to my [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1243300)). Right now I'm just passively hoping 14.04 will have a fix.

Comment: I _think_ it works for me, though I can't be completely sure, as it seemed rather sporadic when the error would occur. However, I did "sudo chmod +s nmcli" first, wouldn't that be necessary for this to work (or adding sudo in the script, and a NOPASSWD for nmcli in the sudoers file)? Or does the script execute with sudo privileges regardless?

Answer (score 19):

I have the same issue.
Looks like it's related to power management that does not wake network-manager.
After resuming, you can open a terminal and type:

> sudo service network-manager restart

It should bring up the network.

Comment: Thanks. I just filed a bug for acpi-support, perhaps you can add to it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi-support/+bug/1243300 I'm holding off accepting your answer because someone might come up with an actual fix.

Comment: wow, after so much toiling with many script this worked for me...Thanks