# No wifi, network discovery, or recognised wireless interface after hybernation on 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, adapter

Recently upgraded to 14.04.  Worked great until computer went to sleep.  On wake, all signs of anything wireless had disappeared as mentioned in title.  I've combed the forums, googled and tried so many things I've lost track.  I finally did a new install.  This is a fresh install, connected via ethernet, but I previously installed back ports, tried ndis, started/stopped nm, and many other suggestions.  The problem remains. I've manually turned off/on the switch for wireless on the laptop, but am unable to fn toggle the led on.  However, when I get into my Bios, the internal wireless is enabled and the led turns on until I save and exit.  Then it turns off again.  Any knowledge appreciated.

Specs:  Memory 5.3 GiB Processor AMD A6-3400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4 Gallium 0.4 on AMD SUMO OS Type 64-bit Disk 732.5 GB

Here is some relevant output. [1]:  http://pastebin.com/wPr8n8D6  [2]:  http://pastebin.com/VdMDi7gn

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue on several units.  Mainly newer laptops and desktop PCs.  Here is how I solved it:

[Network disabled on some wake-ups on saucy laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362933/network-disabled-on-some-wake-ups-on-saucy-laptop)

Create a small script that wakes the network manager up.

Comment: I tried the work arounds  for the bug, to no avail.  Doesn't seem like that is my particular  problem.  I forgot to mention that I am not able to toggle  wireless on/off with the fn  button  either, and "wireless" is not even included in nm.  Would a screen capture of lsmod be of use?  Maybe the link provided below will be of use?  I don't know.  http://pastebin.com/iRY6m6w1

Comment: Are you using Lubuntu by any chance?

Comment: No. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.